# ANTLR: Use First Token of next statement to terminate the preceeing one

Tags: sql, sql-server, parsing, antlr

I am having some issues to related to statement termination for an SQL grammar. Currently it supports statement termination through semicolon ';' token. Making this as optional makes the grammar go out of memory. I want to know whether I can match the first token of next statement as a terminator for previous one without consuming it.  Here is a snippet of my parser grammar.

```
unit_statement
: statement SEMICOLON!
;

 statement
options{
backtrack=true;
}
:   
     declare_statement
|    assignment_statement
|    sql_statement
;
```

Here the sql_statement rule must end with a semicolon but declare_statement should not. I am using ANTLR 3